# Null measure implies empty interior

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification

I tried writing a proof for an exercise i found in my **Real Analysis** book which claims the following:

***Problem:***

If a set $X \subset \mathbb{R}$ has null measure, then it must have empty interior.

***Context/Relevant definitions/Notation:***

**-> Null measure:** One says that $X \subset \mathbb{R}$ has null measure, which we will denote by writing $m(X) = 0$ when, given $\epsilon > 0$ one can obtain a countable collection of open intervals $I_{1}, I_{2}, \ldots, I_{n}, \ldots$ such that:

$$X \subset I_{1} \cup \cdots \cup I_{n} \cup \ldots$$ and $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|I_{n}\right|<\varepsilon$$

**-> Interior point:**

Given $X \subset \mathbb{R}$ a point $x \in X$ is called an interior point when there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that:

$$
(x-\varepsilon, x+\varepsilon) \subset X
$$

We will denote by $int(X)$ the set of all interior points of $X$.

**Attempt:**

Given $X \subset \mathbb{R}$, suppose by contradiction that $int(X) \neq \varnothing$. Then, there exists $\alpha \in int(X)$ such that $(x-\bar{\varepsilon}, \alpha+\bar{\varepsilon}) \subset X$ for some $\bar{\varepsilon} > 0$

On the other hand, since $m(X) = 0$, given $\epsilon > 0$ one can obtain a countable collection of open intervals $I_{1}, I_{2}, \ldots, I_{n}, \ldots$ such that:

$$X \subset I_{1} \cup \cdots \cup I_{n} \cup \ldots$$ and $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|I_{n}\right|<\varepsilon$$

However, by taking $\epsilon=\frac{\bar{\varepsilon}}{4}>0$ we see that:

$$
(\alpha-\varepsilon, \alpha+\varepsilon) \subset(\alpha-\bar{\varepsilon}, \alpha+\bar{\varepsilon}) \subset X \subset \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} I_{n}
$$

which means that $\alpha$ is such that: $$\alpha \in
I_{j} \doteq\left(a_j, b_{j}\right)
$$

for some $j \in \mathbb{N}$

Since $\alpha$ is an interior point, it follows that: $$
(\alpha-\bar{\varepsilon}, \alpha+\bar{\varepsilon}) \subset I_{j} = (a_{j}, b_{j})
$$

Finally, since
$\left|I_{j}\right|=b_{j}-a_{j}>(\alpha+\bar{\varepsilon})-(\alpha-\bar{\varepsilon}) = 2\bar{\varepsilon}$ we get a contradiction, as $
\sum_{n \in N}\left|I_{n}\right|>\varepsilon
$, which is impossible, because $m(X) = 0$

I would appreciate if someone could criticize my work and check if the solution is indeed correct!

Thanks in advance, Lucas

Comment: I think is easier to note that if $X$ contains the interval $(a,b)$ then $mX \ge b-a >0$.

Comment: It does $not$ follow that $(\alpha -\bar \varepsilon,\,\alpha +\bar \varepsilon)\subset I_j.$

Comment: But isn't $\alpha$ an interior point?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $X$ has non-empty interior in $\Bbb R$ it contains some $x$ and for some $r>0$, $(x-r, x+r) \subseteq X$ from which it follows that

$$\mu X \ge \mu((x-r,x+r)) = 2r > 0$$

Comment: Nice! Is everything ok regarding what i have done? Is it correct?